# Present continuous

Tags: present-continuous

Why is it incorrect to say 'we are have a meeting today?' It follows the rules of the present continuous subject + aux verb to be + verb + ing. So why is it incorrect?

Comment: In this sentence, "a meeting" is a noun, not a verb. The verb that needs the "ing" is "have."

Answer (score 1):

It actually doesn't quite follow the rules of the present continuous.  The -ing should follow the verb, which is "to have" not "meeting".  In this case, "meeting" is a noun and a direct object.
It should be "we are having a meeting today".